# How to apply TailwindCSS styles dynamically from a CMS?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, astrojs

I want to present categories on my article cards with different styles depending on the category itself. The styles are not applied if they come from the CMS, but if I add them statically, they are.

Here is my Categories.Astro file:

```
---
const {categories} = Astro.props
console.log(categories)
---

<div class="flex gap-2">
  {
    categories?.map((category: any) => (
      <div
        class={`${category?.style?.backgroundColor || ""} ${category?.style?.textColor || ""} ${
          category?.style?.hoverStyle || ""
        } text-xs font-bold uppercase px-3 py-1 rounded-full mr-1 mb-1 text-center flex justify-center items-center`}
      >
        {category?.name}
      </div>
    ))
  }
</div>
```

I tried with a React component in a Next.js project with the same approach as above to see if Astro was not working for me, but that didn't work either.

My added console.log (categories) provides me with all the data, and it does render the name of the categories on the page. This is an example of one of my categories:

```
 {
    _createdAt: '2023-02-22T08:08:32Z',
    _id: 'aba04de4-35e4-4b94-8499-e7070b838ef4',
    _rev: 'bjKRkMZtbKC9GgwKF3eReN',
    _type: 'category',
    _updatedAt: '2023-02-28T05:28:47Z',
    description: 'This category is all about Javascript.',
    name: 'Javascript',
    slug: { _type: 'slug', current: 'javascript' },
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'bg-yellow-200 ',
      hoverStyle: 'hover:bg-yellow-300 hover:text-black',
      mainColor: 'text-yellow-200 ',
      textColor: 'text-black '
    }
  }
```

Here is what is rendered on the page. For instance, it should have had a background of `bg-yellow-200`:

[image]

If I inspect the element I get the following for the JavaScript category:

```
<div 
class="bg-yellow-200 text-black hover:bg-yellow-300 hover:text-black text-xs font-bold uppercase px-3 py-1 rounded-full mr-1 mb-1 text-center flex justify-center items-center">
   Javascript
</div>
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

It seems like adding a [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) in the tailwind.config.js file is working, but it doesn't seem right. Is there a better way of making sure the styles get applied?

Comment: I guess there are only two ways - safelist (which I prefer) or use CDN (this way you will load whole TailwindCSS bundle). Tailwind cannot see classes which he knows nothing about (that comes from CMS). One question - style object comes from backend and every key can be changed as you wish? Maybe consider to use another strategy - let's say you have predefined style types (primary, secondary, yellow, blue, etc) with classes list and choose classes from this object by color type from backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tailwind does not parse or execute any code](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth) so it can't find the class names from your API

You can use [Safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) or [Raw content](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-raw-content) to get around this

Answer (score 0):

While not specific to React, with our in-house PHP-based CMS (multi-user and multi-site) we keep a track of classes used for each page.  A page is built up using components so when anything on that page changes, we rebuild the class list from the components on it.

We then queue a server-side routine to rebuild the Tailwind CSS file for that web site which happens more or less immediately.  That way we're still using a compiled Tailwind CSS which only contains the classes we need and nothing more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).